# Cp=Cv for isochoric processes?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics

According to the first law of thermodynamics, ∆U = ∆H + work done, where magnitude of work done is given by W = PdV.

In an isochoric process work done would be zero (provided the external pressure doesn't change, which is usually the case), and the above equation would give us ∆H = ∆U. If we were to use the values: delta H = nCp∆T and delta U = nCv∆T, we would get Cp = Cv, which is false.

I also know that one of the ways to find the relation Cp = Cv + R would be to substitute the PdV with ∆nRT, but if we were to use the formula for an isochoric process as it is, then the result would be Cp = Cv.

The only counter argument to this that I could think of was that the ∆T in the above formulae were different (with the condition that the ∆T in ∆H pertains to the change in temperature on the condition that pressure remains constant and the condition of constant volume for that of ∆U). But even this argument was squashed by a youtube video I watched [where it is mentioned that the above formulae could be used regardless of the process the gas undergoes](https://youtu.be/rXNuxRaZ9A4). So where exactly am I going wrong?

Please note that I'm in 12th grade so my knowledge of thermodynamics and some of the math used in it (such as partial derivatives) is limited.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/410009. Also, YouTube as a platform is designed for entertainment and collecting ad revenue, not rigorous studying.

Comment: $\Delta H = \Delta U + p \cdot \Delta V + V  \cdot \Delta p$, so for isochoric system  $\Delta H = \Delta U  + V  \cdot \Delta p$.

Comment: Cp is isobaric molar heat capacity. Cv is isochoric molar heat capacity. The system cannot have 2 heat capacities at the same heating process. You heat it up either isobarically with Cp , or isochorically with Cv. ( or neither of both ways, then neither of capacities is applicable.)

Comment: @Poutnik so you're saying that the assumptions of those formulae being correct in all processes is the problem?

Comment: dH/dT=dU/dT + d(pV)/dT=nCv + nR=nCp. It is valid for ideal gas, not generally. // The fact that dH/dT=nCp does not mean Cp=Cv, as dQ/dT=dU = nCv <> dH for isochoric process and dQ/dT=dH =nCp <> dU for isobaric process.